# AttributeError when I import model from another app

Tags: django, django-models, import, models

I don't know why but I got an error: `AttributeError: module 'downloads.models' has no attribute 'AbstractDownload'` in this place: `class Download(models_downloads.AbstractDownload):`

In download app I have already `AbstractDownload` class

Here is my model from products

```
products/models.py
from downloads import models as models_downloads

    class Download(models_downloads.AbstractDownload):
        product = models.ForeignKey('products.Product', related_name='downloads')
        file = FilerFileField(related_name="file_products_download")
```

Here is downloads models

```
downloads/models.py
class AbstractDownload(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    file = FilerFileField(related_name="file_abstract_download")
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/path/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/path/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/path/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/path/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/path/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/path/venv/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/path/www/downloads/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    from products import models as products_models
  File "/path/www/products/models.py", line 31, in <module>
    class Download(models_downloads.AbstractDownload):
AttributeError: module 'downloads.models' has no attribute 'AbstractDownload'
```

Comment: Did you run the proper migrations?

Comment: I made python `manage.py migrate downloads zero` and `python manage.py migrate products zero` and then changed code. But I still get an error @alessioferri20

Comment: please try manage.py makemigrations and then manage.py migrate without products zero or downloads zero

Comment: I got `AttributeError: module 'downloads.models' has no attribute 'AbstractDownload'`

Comment: when you run the commands above?

Comment: please check my edit @Alasdair

Comment: @user9192656 this traceback occur when you run makemigrations or migrate?

Comment: I undo all migrations to zero. This traceback is after python manage.py makemigations @alessioferri20

Comment: @user9192656 can you please show all the imports for the two files? maybe you have wrong typing on them

Comment: and please change from downloads import models as models_downloads
to from downloads.models import AbstractDownload

Answer (score 0):

You have a circular import. Your `downloads/models.py` has:

```
from products import models as products_models
```

But your `products/models.py` has

```
from downloads import models as models_downloads
```

You haven't shown how you use `products_models`, so we can't really say how to fix it. Here's a few suggestions:

- Perhaps that import isn't necessary if you use a string for foreign keys, e.g. `models.ForeignKey('downloads.ModelName')`
- Perhaps you could move `AbstractDownload` and `Download` so that they are in the same models, so that you don't need an import
- If you use `products_models` inside a method, you could move the import inside the method. I would avoid this if possible.